# Can't view CM contact sent to a now-deleted user

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, contact

When a CM contact is sent, then the user destroyed or deleted, viewing the message gives a 500.

Mod messages still show after a user is destroyed; CM contacts should too.

Comment: I already went crying to Adam Lear about this. :P

Comment: I am technically correct, dammit. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQclk.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am shocked to discover that being [technically correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQclk.png) is not, in fact, the best kind of correct. Very sadness. Wow.

(Fix is out in production now. Thanks!)